# Does "Accio" make the summoned object take the best/most careful path?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

Does it take the most sensible path or the most direct, and is it one speed only?

For example, in the 2nd book when Harry and Ron are visiting Hermione in the hospital wing, they see the crumpled up paper in her fist. If they had known the Summoning Charm and summoned the paper, would it have carefully manuevered itself out of her fist to avoid tearing it (like they had to do manually), or would it have shot out directly out as one speed only type of thing, no matter if it tore?

Comment: Considering how Harry moved his broom during the Triwiz and how Hermione summoned the Horcrux books after the funeral, I always assumed the objects take a sensible path, then again, the twins brooms slammed straight through Umbridge's CLOSED office door, when crashing through windows would have been the safer route; at least less risk of the brooms getting damaged by crashing through glass than a wooden door.

Comment: perhaps it depends on the skill of the caster? Harry Potter has many instances where it is hinted that the quality of the outcome of a spell is dependent on the proficiency of the spell caster.

Comment: In OotP, when Fred and George summon their brooms, Harry mentions that he had to duck to avoid being hit by the brooms. So, maybe not the "most careful" path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously there is no clear evidence about it on the books.

However, following the examples noticed from different comments I think the object follows the path the mage's mind is dictating, so depending on the hurry, the situation, and the effort put into the spell probably the route can change.

Think in it like driving a car. When you drive to a destination that you know perfectly you can do it almost without thinking. Your drive would be fast, clean and safe.

If you are hurried you'll probably need to pay more attention to the road, and probably your drive would be a bit careless, but you'll arrive your destination earlier.

And if you are driving through a place that you don't know, you will need to put all your attention in directing your car and navigating the unknown surroundings.

So I think this is something similar. If you know exactly where the object is and how to get from there to where you are, your brain can dictate a precise and safe route almost without thinking in it. While if you are not familiarized, you are hurried or you are just careless about it, the route your brain traces will be less efficient and you'll need to put more insight in it.

Comment: You may be onto something there. Maybe the wizard needs to actually *guide* the object mentally. Maybe the object never moves by itself at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my modest opinion, Accio is fantastic.
This said, I like to think of magic as like "spelled words that make something happen".
Now, a note. During the Triwizard, Harry could not take his broom to the trial, having to summon it. *But he knew where it was!*

Next book, during Fred and George's escape, we see the two of them summon their own brooms, always via Accio, *from a non precised point somewhere in Hogwarts cellars.*

Thus the theory of the mage guiding the object with thought is not applicable.
Moreover, we see Molly Weasley Accio the mous from the twins'pockets at the beginning of the fourth book. She knew they had them, but not where.

**My answer to the question is then YES.**

Accio is a spell that given the caster knowledge of what to summon, independently from the knowledge of position, can track them and move it toward the caster.

A little consideration: as an aspiring engineer, I also find interesting the conservation of momentum described in the seventh book, when Harry casts Accio on Hagrid and gets pulled towards him and not he contrary. This means "Accioing" a house, or whatever object with a mass considerably higher than mine will make me splat against it? Funny!